# Using meta tags in a Twig template

Tags: twig, content-management-system, flat-file, picocms

I am in the process of experimenting with Pico CMS which uses a flat files organized in hierarchical folders and Twig as its layout engine.  I have studied the Twig documentation and looked at a few example templates.  One of the things I have consistently found is the way they incorporate meta data.  Here is one example

```
---
Description:Page Description Placeholder
---
```

in the markdown file, say index.md, and then

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ meta.description|striptags }}" />
```

in the corresponding Twig template, index.twig

I understand what is happening here.  However, my attempts to find a description for this way to handle meta data have failed.  I may well be looking for the wrong thing or have somehow managed to miss this in the Twig docs.  I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to put me on the right track

Comment: This functionality is not included in twig itself. So (without knowing pico cms) I'd guess it's a custom twig extension. Probably this: https://github.com/picocms/Pico/blob/master/lib/PicoTwigExtension.php

Comment: This is indeed a Pico extension.  I found it eventually in the [Pico docs] (http://picocms.org/docs/#themes)